# Mongoid 7 + mongoid-rspec compatibility issues

Tags: ruby, rspec, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am integrating mongoid-rspec with Mongoid 7 and while running the command rspec it show me below mentioned error trace:

```
cannot load such file -- mongoid/relations
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/mongoid-rspec-4.0.0/lib/matchers/associations.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/mongoid-rspec-4.0.0/lib/mongoid/rspec.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@wavedio/gems/mongoid-rspec-4.0.0/lib/mongoid-rspec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# /home/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'

Configured mongoid-rspec using this link https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-rspec
```

Rails - 5.1.6

Ruby - 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the latest released version of `mongoid-rspec` 4.0.0 does not support mongoid 7, as of now. See here: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-rspec/pull/212.

I am using it like this in my project:

```
gem 'mongoid-rspec', github: 'mongoid/mongoid-rspec', ref: '68c95b133be1a1482fe882e39afd33262147d1f4'
```

It worked for me.